# Declare variable inside array's element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anyone can explain why this code works in javascript ?

```
let people = [
  "Jeremy",
  "Male",
  (address = [(domicile = [{ province: "jakarta", city: "jakpus" }])]),
  (origin = [{ provinceOrigin: "Lampung", cityOrigin: "Bandar Lampung" }]),
];
console.log(address); //[ [ { province: 'jakarta', city: 'jakpus' } ] ]
```

does this code declare a variable inside array's element ? but why i cannot declare the variable using let, const, or var ?

Comment: This creates implicit global varaibles and throws an error in strict mode. Basically `x = y` expression evaluates `y`. So, something like `[x=y]`, evaluates to `[y]` and creates a global variable `x`

Comment: Assignments are an *expression*. An expression can occur within other expressions. Whether you write `a = b` on its own line or within an array declaration has the same effect.

Comment: but why we cannot use let, const, or var on that expression ? @deceze

Comment: Because those are statements, not expressions.